# how to get results of multiple queries through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a input field which filter the data based upon the value of input field value. I am using ajax call to filter the data at run time. But the problem is I am using multiple queries and foreach loop to fetch my desired results like I am getting data of a person: name, email, phone, departments. A person is working on multiple departments so I am using foreach loop to fetch all his departments along with his name, email and phone.

When I output my data,the detail of first person coming correct but in the 2nd person means in 2nd row department column also show the departments of first person and 3rd showing the 2nd person departments and so on. how can i show the right detail of a person?

here is my code:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#cmp_name").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
             'url':"filter.php",
            'data':{name:$("#cmp_name").val()},
            'method':'GET',
            'success':function(name){
                //alert(data);
                 $("#datas").html(name);            
            }
        })

  });
 });
</script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name"  name="cmp_name"  id="cmp_name">
```

and here is my filter.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 $dpt = "";
 $ret = "";
 $query = mysql_query("select id,name,phone,country_id,departments from persons where name like '%$name%'");

 while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $name = $data['name'];
     $phone = $data['phone'];
     $country_id = $data['country_id'];
     $queryr= mysql_query("select country from countries where country_id = $country_id'");
                        $$country = mysql_fetch_array($queryr);
                        $country_name = $country['country'];





     $depart = $data['departments'];
     $department=explode(",",$depart);
        foreach($department as $departments){

              $depart_fetch = mysql_query("select department_name from departments where id='$departments'");
                                        $fetch1 = mysql_fetch_array($depart_fetch);
                                        $depart_list = $fetch1['description'];
                                    $dpt=$dpt."<div> ".$depart_list." </div>";

                                }
                $ret=$ret."<tr><td> ".$name." </td><td> ".$phone." </td><td> ".$country_name." </td><td> ".$dpt."</td></tr>";
                }
    echo $ret;
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO. You also should use prepared statements. As your code is, it is subject to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: `$depart = $data['departments'];
     $department=explode(",",$depart);` This suggests your database is badly de-normalised, if you have multiple ID values in a single field in a single row. Read about entity-relationship design and database normalisation and create a correct structure. You need a many-to-many relationship between persons and departments, involving a separate linking table to describe how each person links to their departments (and vice versa). Then your queries and the subsequent work will become much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write `$dpt = "";` just before `foreach($department as $departments){`. Otherwise it just keeps on adding to the list on every loop, instead of making a new list for each person.

This will fix your immediate issue, however you should also strongly note the comments I made above regarding your out-of-date data access methods and your broken database design and aim to fix those in the near future, before putting your code into production use.

Comment: thank you so much @ADyson. My issue solved. and i will go surely fix other drawbacks before putting code into production use.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be wrong: `$dpt=$dpt."<div> ".$cns." </div>";`.
I don't see where `$cns` comes from. I believe it should be: `$dpt="<div> ".$depart_list." </div>";`
This removes the duplication of departments in `$dpt`.

Comment: yes it is $depart_list. but i am facing the same issue